# Spinner not charge list

Tags: kotlin, spinner

I'm getting a list of company names but I can only get Spinner to show me one item from the list.

What can I do so that the spinner loads the empresa list, it only shows an item

```
    private fun initCharacter(clientes : List<ResultsEmpresa>) {

    clientes.forEach{
        val empresas = it.empresa
        val listCliente: MutableList<SpinnerClientes> = ArrayList()
        listCliente.add(SpinnerClientes(empresas))
        val spnAdapter = SpinnerClientesAdapter(this@AddObra,
            R.layout.kecamatan, R.id.spinnerText, listCliente)
        spnClients!!.adapter = spnAdapter
        spnClients!!.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, position: Int, id: Long,)
                {
                    val desaDetails = spnAdapter.getItem(position)
                    textView_empresa!!.text = desaDetails.nom_empresa
                }
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is:
The list should have been created before the forEach

```
private fun initCharacter(clientes : List<ResultsEmpresa>) {

    val listCliente: MutableList<SpinnerClientes> = ArrayList()

    clientes.forEach{
        val empresas = it.empresa

        listCliente.add(SpinnerClientes(empresas))
        val spnAdapter = SpinnerClientesAdapter(this@AddObra,
            R.layout.kecamatan, R.id.spinnerText, listCliente)
        spnClients!!.adapter = spnAdapter
        spnClients!!.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, position: Int, id: Long,)
                {
                    val desaDetails = spnAdapter.getItem(position)
                    textView_empresa!!.text = desaDetails.nom_empresa
                }
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            }
    }
}
```